# SQL - Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql-server

G-day All,

I have a SQL statement that is running relatively well however I am having issue when trying to include an additional criteria, I believe it is due to my order of operations however I can't seem to figure it out. See below for the current code:

```
SELECT 
WorkOrderNumber,
AssetDescription,
AssetNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN WorkOrderDescription IS NULL
        THEN WorkOrderHistoryDescription
    ELSE WorkOrderDescription
END AS RevWorkOrderDescription,
RaisedDateTime,
FinishedDateTime,
CASE 
    WHEN PriorityDescription = 'Critical > 4 hours'
        THEN 'P1'
    WHEN PriorityDescription = 'High > 8 hours'
        THEN 'P2'
    WHEN PriorityDescription = 'Medium > 48 hours'
        THEN 'P3'
    WHEN PriorityDescription = 'Low > 72 hours'
        THEN 'P4'
    ELSE 'Shutdown - no end date'
END AS Priority,
ComponentCodeName,
(dbo.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + dbo.Contact.LastName) AS RaisedBy
FROM dbo.WorkOrder
LEFT JOIN dbo.Asset ON dbo.Asset.AssetID = dbo.WorkOrder.AssetID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ComponentCode ON dbo.ComponentCode.ComponentCodeID = dbo.WorkOrder.ComponentCodeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Priority ON dbo.Priority.PriorityID = dbo.WorkOrder.PriorityID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact ON dbo.Contact.ContactID = dbo.WorkOrder.CreatedByContactID
WHERE (
    (
        RaisedDateTime BETWEEN '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND '2015-05-31 23:59:59.999'
        )
    OR (
        FinishedDateTime BETWEEN '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND '2015-05-31 23:59:59.999'
        AND RaisedDateTime < '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'
        )
    )
AND PreventativeMaintenanceID IS NULL
ORDER BY WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber
```

What I am trying to do is to include all WorkOrders that have a *PreventativeMaintenanceID* of NULL or returned all WorkOrders that have a *dbo.PreventativeMaintenance.IsStandard* value of 1. When I try to add the join and include `AND dbo.WorkOrder.PreventativeMaintenanceID IS NULL OR dbo.PreventativeMaintenance.IsStandard` the query appears to disregard my chosen date ranges.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I am still relatively green when it comes to SQL so any comments on the balance of the code would be great.

Comment: `AND ( ...IS NULL. OR ...IsStandard )` Note parentheses.

Comment: Side note: [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Or with anything, really.

Comment: Ahh I can't believe it was something that simple.. Thanks for the assistance (along with the tip regarding BETWEEN)!